# Bootstrap Radio Button Group Posts Wrong Value after Keyboard Select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, radio-group, buttongroup

I have this bootstrap button group with radio buttons:

```
<div id="MyField" data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="radio" name="MyField" value="Val1" autocomplete="off">First</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active"><input type="radio" name="MyField" value="Val2" autocomplete="off" checked="">Second</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="radio" name="MyField" value="Val3" autocomplete="off">Third</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="radio" name="MyField" value="Val4" autocomplete="off">Fourth</label>
</div>
```

If I select the value using the mouse, everything works fine. However, if I move to the group using the tab key and select another option using the keyboard arrow keys, the following happens:

- The active button changes visually as expected
- The change javascript event (handled using jQuery $('#MyField').change(...)) is fired as expected
- **When the form is submitted, the original value of the default selected radio button is sent to the backend.**

Any ideas on why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in bootstrap 3.3.4 which is fixed in 3.3.7. After an update, everything works fine.

Comment: I am still running into this bug in Bootstrap 4.  Is there a work around I can use?

Comment: For me this resolved itself in Bootstrap 4 when I upgraded from 4.3.1 to 4.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to just include an *onfocus* attribute to the inputs.

`<label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="radio" name="MyField" value="Val1" autocomplete="off" onfocus="$(this).click();">First</label>`